# Estimating Correlation Matrices

Tags: estimation, correlation, matrix

I am trying to obtain the correlation matrices of two random signals. Both of them, $ X $ and $ Y $, are white Gaussian Noise, with unitary variance. However, they are correlated, with correlation coefficient $ \rho $. I generate $ Y $ from $ X $ using the following expression
$$
Y = \rho X + \sqrt{1 - \rho^2}Q,
$$
where, $ Q $ is also white Gaussian noise with unitary variance ($\sigma^2 = 1$).
The correlation matrices I compute as $R_{X} = X X^{H}/N $, where $ N $ is the number of realizations of $ X $. I do the equivalent for $ R_{YY} $.

This is my Matlab code:

```
nSamples = 1e3; % Number of samples in each trial of the process
nTrials = 1e4; % Number of trials
rho = 0.65; % Correlation between two stochastic process

%% Independent samples
X = randn(nSamples, nTrials); % Each trial in each column
Y = rho*X + sqrt(1-rho^2)*randn(nSamples, nTrials);

Rxx = X*X'/nTrials;
Ryy = Y*Y'/nTrials;
```

From this, I get, for instance:

```
Rxx(1:5, 1:5)

ans =

    1.0031    0.0227    0.0113   -0.0025    0.0130
    0.0227    0.9916    0.0005   -0.0094   -0.0030
    0.0113    0.0005    1.0065    0.0002   -0.0006
   -0.0025   -0.0094    0.0002    1.0093    0.0154
    0.0130   -0.0030   -0.0006    0.0154    0.9979
```

which is what I was expecting. However, when I try to add correlation between the samples of the same signal, things go wrong. For instance, first I tried to use the filter function, with the taps $ 1, -r $ in the feedback filter, where $ r $ is the correlation coefficient of an autoregressive process of first order. Here is the code:

```
r = 0.8;

% Method 1:
fw = [1 -r];
fw = fw/sum(fw);

X2 = filter(1, fw, randn(nSamples, nTrials));
Y2 = filter(1, fw, randn(nSamples, nTrials));
Y2 = rho*X2 + sqrt(1-rho^2)*Y2;

Rxx2 = X2*X2'/nTrials;
Ryy2 = Y2*Y2'/nTrials;
```

When I look at the results, for instance of $ R_{XX} $, I get

```
Rxx2(1:5, 1:5)

ans =

    0.0402    0.0323    0.0256    0.0203    0.0165
    0.0323    0.0667    0.0536    0.0431    0.0348
    0.0256    0.0536    0.0829    0.0664    0.0532
    0.0203    0.0431    0.0664    0.0928    0.0747
    0.0165    0.0348    0.0532    0.0747    0.1009
```

which is not what I was expecting. Although the non-diagonal values seems symmetric, the diagonal itself does not contain consistent values, as before. I understand they would not be close to 1, but that they would be close to each other.

I also tried without the filter function:

```
X = randn(nSamples, nTrials); % Each trial in each column
X2 = zeros(nSamples, nTrials);
X2(1, :) = X(1, :);

Y = randn(nSamples, nTrials); % Each trial in each column
Y2 = zeros(nSamples, nTrials);
Y2(1, :) = Y(1, :);

for k = 2:nSamples
    
    X2(k, :) = r*X(k-1, :) + sqrt(1-r^2)*randn(1, nTrials);
    Y2(k, :) = r*Y(k-1, :) + sqrt(1-r^2)*randn(1, nTrials);
    
end
Y2 = rho*X2 + sqrt(1-rho^2)*Y2;

Rxx2 = X2*X2'/nTrials;
Ryy2 = Y2*Y2'/nTrials;
```

which gave me

```
Rxx2(1:5, 1:5)

ans =

    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000
    0.0000    0.9916   -0.0007    0.0122   -0.0074
    0.0000   -0.0007    1.0157   -0.0051   -0.0104
   -0.0000    0.0122   -0.0051    0.9996   -0.0003
    0.0000   -0.0074   -0.0104   -0.0003    0.9928
```

which has an acceptable diagonal, except for the first element.

My question is: is this the right way to compute the correlation matrix? Is there anything that I am doing wrong? I am also not sure whether the way I am correlating the samples are correct or not.

Thanks in advance for the help.

---

**Update:** I noticed an error in the code using the AR process. Where it was `X2(1) = X(1);` I changed to `X2(1, :) = X(1, :);`. This was resulting in the first column and row of the correlation matrix with zeros. With this fix, I am getting

```
Rxx2(1:5, 1:5)

ans =

    1.0167    0.8181    0.0004    0.0109    0.0019
    0.8181    1.0111   -0.0044    0.0087   -0.0043
    0.0004   -0.0044    0.9928    0.0029    0.0122
    0.0109    0.0087    0.0029    0.9989    0.0132
    0.0019   -0.0043    0.0122    0.0132    1.0224
```

which has the correct diagonal, and $R_{XX}(1)$ apparently correct. The other elements does not seem to be correct, however. I still have not figured out the problem with the filter method, though.

Comment: $Y$ doesn't have unit variance but a variance of $1-\rho^2+\rho^4$.; the factor in front of $Q$ needs to be $\sqrt{1-\rho^2}$, not just $1-\rho^2$, then the variance of $Y$ becomes $1$.

Comment: Hi @MarcusMüller, thank you for taking the time to point that out. You are correct. I am actually using the square root in my codes. I have just forgot it in the minimal example that I wrote to show here. I will update the question, since correcting it did not change the matrices' behavior I have shown.